# S-Control Refreshes Page Endlessly (one-click owner change)

Tags: administration, button, case, s-control

This code is actually on the AppExchange and is supposed to give one-click self-assignment of ownership on a case.  When put onto the Layout, it never renders the control, and refreshes the page every few seconds endlessly.  I am not seeing the problem in the code.  Anyone have an idea?   OR, have a solution that would work via a simple programmed button with a URL call or something similar?   Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>

<head>
    <script src="/soap/ajax/10.0/connection.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/sCSS/Theme2/en/dStandard.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
            var caseid = "{!Case.Id}";
            var userid = "{!$User.Id}";
            var CaseToUpdate = new sforce.SObject("Case");
                CaseToUpdate.set("Id", caseid);
                CaseToUpdate.set("OwnerId", userid);
                var Result = sforce.connection.update([CaseToUpdate]);
                        if(Result[0].getBoolean("success"))
                        {
                            function redirect() { parent.frames.location.replace("/{!Case.Id}"); } 
                            redirect(); 
                        }
                        else {
                        alert("Error");
                        }   
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Assign Case to Self](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016caOEAQ) s-control would need to be placed in the buttons section of the details page to function correctly.

It appears you can no longer add this s-control to the correct location in the page layout. Placing it elsewhere in the page layout would explain the continuous refresh loop that you are experiencing.

[image: AssignToMyself SControl]

---

One option is to convert the button from being an s-control to being inline Javascript.

Change the "Assign To Myself" custom Case button to have the "Execute JavaScript" behavior and make the Script:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT ("/soap/ajax/13.0/connection.js")}

var caseid = "{!Case.Id}";
var userid = "{!$User.Id}";
var CaseToUpdate = new sforce.SObject("Case");
CaseToUpdate.set("Id", caseid);
CaseToUpdate.set("OwnerId", userid);
var Result = sforce.connection.update([CaseToUpdate]);
if(Result[0].getBoolean("success"))
{
    function redirect() { parent.frames.location.replace("/{!Case.Id}"); } 
    redirect(); 
}
else {
    alert("Error");
}
```

Then add this new button to the Custom Buttons section of the Case Details page.

Comment: I'm just no at all familiar with writing S-Controls.  This is a package from AppExchange, by Salesforce, free to download.  :-/

Comment: Can you provide a link to the AppExcahnge package and/or documentation for it?

Comment: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016caOEAQ  ....  Instructions = "add the button to your layout"  ;-)

Comment: Updated Anwswer worked like a charm... thanks, @DanielBallinger.